# Swap rate with coupons

Tags: solution-verification, finance, actuarial-science

Suppose you were given the following information about the prices of zero-bond coupons, all with a maturity of $1$:

The price of a $1$ year zero-coupon bond is $0.943$.

The price of a $2$ year zero-coupon bond is $W$.

If the above prices describe the current term structure and assuming that at time $0$, the constant notional level swap rate is $0.065826$, what is the value of $W$?

My attempt:

$$R = \frac{1 - P_{t_n}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} P_{t_i}} = \frac{1 - W}{0.943 + W}$$

But this is $0.065826$ so

$$\frac{1 - W}{0.943 + W} = 0.065826$$

This gives that $W = 0.88$.

Is this correct? It can't be that simple, can it? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Seems correct assuming annual fixed payments.

Comment: @fesman Thank you for responding. What if the payments weren't fixed?

Comment: The swap rate is defined as the coupon for the fixed leg so I think these payments are fixed by assumption. However, you might receive these e.g. semiannually, which would affect the calculation. Because you were given only annual zeros I assume the swap rate was for annual.

Comment: Okay. Also, could you perhaps take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4154370/812835?